# Given objective value for ILP find parameter is NP hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

For an integer linear program: Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n\times d}$ and two vectors $b \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$, $c \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}$, compute $max\{ c^{\top}x|Ax \leq b, x\geq 0, x\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}\}$ is an NP hard problem.

Also given matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times d}$ and a vector $b \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$, determine whether the set of feasible integer points $max\{ x \in Z^{d}\mid Ax\leq b x \geq 0 \}$ is empty or not is also NP-hard.

> So I wonder, given the objective value of an integer linear program, is finding the parameter where the objective is achieved also NP-hard?

I think this is equivalent to finding the actual feasible point given that the set of feasible integer points is nonempty (due to the fact that we can move the objective to constraints) However, I'm not sure how to show either is NP-hard or not.

Comment: 1. What does "finding the parameter where the objective is achieved" mean?  Can you give a mathematical specification of the problem?  I'm not quite sure what you mean by parameter and objective.  Are you asking whether it is NP-hard to find one feasible point in the feasible region?  2. In your second paragraph, I think you should remove the "max".  Your goal is to determine whether a set is empty or not, rather than to find the max; and the max of a set of vectors is not well-defined.